# Sending queries in parallel with ExecutorService in Java 8

Tags: java, http, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-8

I'm writing a web application in Java (namely using [JavaLite](http://javalite.io/)). In this web application, I have an endpoint which should send a bunch of other requests to a server, when invoked. Since these requests may increase in number, I decided to send these requests in parallel, using the Java Concurrency API introduced in Java 8. My code for sending multiple requests in parallel is as follows:

```
public List<String> searchAll(List<String> keywords) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    List<Callable<List<String>>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : keywords) {
        tasks.add(() -> {
            LOGGER.info("Sending query for key: " + key);
            return sendSearchQuery(key);
        });
    }
    List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        executor.invokeAll(tasks)
                .stream()
                .map(future -> {
                    try {
                        return future.get();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                })
                .forEach((list) ->
                {
                    LOGGER.info("Received list: " + list);
                    all.addAll(list);
                });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return all;
}

private List<String> sendSearchQuery(String query) throws UnirestException {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get(SEARCH_URL)
            .queryString("q", query).asString();
    Map<String, Object> result = JsonHelper.toMap(response.getBody());
//    Get get = Http.get(SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + query);
//    Map<String, Object> result = JsonHelper.toMap(get.text());
    LOGGER.info("Query received in " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000 + " ms for key: " + query);
    return (List<String>) result.get("result");
}
```

And the output for this piece of code is as follows:

```
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Sending query for key: sky
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-2] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Sending query for key: outdoor
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Sending query for key: bridge
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Sending query for key: water
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Query received in 1331 ms for key: water
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Sending query for key: building
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Query received in 1332 ms for key: sky
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-2] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Query received in 1332 ms for key: outdoor
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Query received in 1332 ms for key: bridge
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Query received in 302 ms for key: building
[1324676647@qtp-178658894-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Received list: [16973, 4564, 12392, 1195, 1207, 682, 10518, 10532, 10545, 19328, 10524, 10537, 10551, 19334, 10522, 10535, 10548, 19332, 10521, 10534]
[1324676647@qtp-178658894-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Received list: []
[1324676647@qtp-178658894-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Received list: [4303, 2844, 4366]
[1324676647@qtp-178658894-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Received list: [9490, 1638, 20006, 17715, 17758, 18788, 6071, 11230, 13384, 4940, 18039, 17871, 16629, 6148, 19172, 4263, 4569, 8396, 18643, 4904]
[1324676647@qtp-178658894-0] INFO app.managers.SearchManager - Received list: [17306, 17303, 17305, 17304, 16062, 16156, 16153, 16154, 16061, 9098, 2491, 4368, 22134, 1008, 16152, 16151, 16148, 16155, 16147, 16149]
```

As you can see, I used two different Http libraries ([JavaLite Http](http://javalite.io/http) and [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html)) to see if the problem was with the library I was using, however that doesn't seem to be the case as they both yield the same problem.

The problem here is, the first `n` (number of processor on the machine) queries start and end at the same time. This is normal, however they also take longer than they should. Let's say a single request takes `t` time in normal conditions. In this case, the first `n` queries each take around `n * t` time, and the remaining queries each take `t` time. Am I using the concurrency API wrongly?

**Edit:** The server running on `SEARCH_URL` is deployed on Azure and it can handle multiple requests.

I also tried the following:

- using `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool()`, however the `Executor` I'm using doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem.
- calling `invokeAny()` instead of `invokeAll()`, however the former blocks the main thread until one of the tasks is finished, and only returns the results of that task.

**Edit 2:** So I played around with both the server and the application I'm currently working on. The weird thing is, the server responds to n requests in different times, however the app receives these responses after a time frame which starts with the time first request reaches the server and ends with the time **n**'th response reaches the app. I have no explanation for this behavior.

Comment: What happens if you just put a fixed sleep instead of the http call ? That way we can be sure if its a problem with the executor service or the server issue. Also, please add date-time to your logger and print the output. It will be easier to visualise the problem you explained.

Comment: @MadPiranha it works as expected when I don't send the requests. The problem indeed seems to be about the server itself. I ran the server on localhost and the first `n` responses are indeed sent in a longer amount of time.

Comment: Depending on what "first n requests" mean, your problem may be due to loading and initialization of relevant classes in "java.util.concurrent" package. I remember reading about it somewhere, but sadly I can't recall where exactly.

Comment: If we know that the delay is from the server side then we need to look at that part ! Please update the question.

Comment: @MadPiranha I played with the code some more and it seems the server sends back responses in reasonable times (not all at the same time), however the client gathers the results in larger amounts of time than each of the individual requests, all similar to each other. I will update the question on this.

Comment: Doesn’t Unirest have its own executor, controlling the concurrency?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the completableFuture framework that was brought in for java 8? I could help with you trying to send out everything async.

```
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futures = keywords.parallelStream()
            .map(key -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sendSearchQuery(key), executor))
            .collect(toList());

CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));

try {
    allOf.join();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

List<String> all = futures.stream().filter(CompletableFuture::isCompletedExceptionally)
            .flatMap(future -> future.join().stream())
            .collect(toList());

return all;
```

What this will do will send out all you searchs async, then you call allOf.join(), you wait on everything to return.

The final stream then maps every result back to one list and returns

Answer (score 0):

```
invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
```

- Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and **results when all complete.**

Does your source also have capability to serve multiple requests?

Comment: You're right, the documentation does say "when all complete", however the remaining queries are sent normally and the `Future` objects are returned in time without any problems. Also, there doesn't seem to be any alternatives to `invokeAll()` which executes tasks independent from each other. The server is deployed on Azure and it can handle multiple requests.

Comment: ``invokeAny()`` is there. And if you use ``Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`` you can submit multiple tasks one by one and they will be executed in parallel.

Comment: Also that timing tells us nothing except the fact that it waited for all four requests to complete.

Comment: `invokeAny()` runs a bunch of tasks and returns only the `Future` object for the first task to finish. Even their return types are different. It's not very visible in this example but if I ran like 20 tasks, it would be more apparent that the remaining tasks do run in parallel without problems.

Comment: What's your thinking about the fixedthreadpool or submitting tasks one by one, but they would be executed in parallel.

Comment: I did that too and unfortunately it yields the same result as before.